# How do I sniff on a port for log messages using python?

Tags: python, logging, port, listen

I have log messages being received on server at a port 777, and I would like to parse them as they come in rather than saving them to disk and then parsing them.  What is the best way to do this?  I've looked at the socket module documentation, and the examples there don't really apply to my situation.

tcpdump has a way to view the messages

`tcpdump -Ai eth0 'port 777'`

This basically does what I want, it reads the packets as ASCII on port 777 where my logs are, but I want to use Python (2.7.6) not tcpdump.

Comment: There are lots of examples out there of how to write Python code that accepts incoming connections and does something with the data.  The [very first example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) in the documentation seems like it would be a good starting point.  What about that does not apply to your situation?

Comment: I tried using that example to capture the messages but it didn't work, and I can't figure out why, so I'd like someone to post the most basic example of capturing everything on a port.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried the socket module?

Comment: Is the sender already connected to some other process listening on port 777 on your server?

Comment: if tcpdump is showing you the messages then your sender is already connected to a receiver process on receiver's port 777. So are you trying to replace the receiver or "listen in on"/intercept the ongoing message stream? If you're trying to listen in, you could probably combine tcpdump and python. There's probably a python libpcap wrapper for using tcpdump directly from python.

Comment: As you can see in the comments, we're still not entirely clear what you're trying to do.  Can you tell us more about the application involved? Is it tcp or udp traffic? *Is* something already running on your host that is receiving this traffic?

Comment: I may have not asked the right question, my apologies.  I have log messages being sent to a socket, and I want to sniff the packets and read them as ascii using Python.  Similar to how tcpdump sniffs with the -A argument.

Answer (score 0):

[Blog Post](http://3gfp.com/wp/2015/03/sniffing-tcp-packets-with-python/) | 
[GitHub](https://github.com/sr105/pypcap_example/) | [LGPLv2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt)

```
# pip install pcap dpkt
import pcap
import dpkt
import time
import binascii

DEBUG = False

def print_hex_string_nicely(hex_string):
    index = 0
    result = ''
    while hex_string:
        result += '{:08x}: '.format(index)
        index += 16
        line, hex_string = hex_string[:32], hex_string[32:]
        while line:
            two_bytes, line = line[:4], line[4:]
            if two_bytes:
                result += two_bytes + ' '
        result = result[:-1] + '\n'
    print result

def hex_dump_packet(packet_data):
    print_hex_string_nicely(binascii.hexlify(packet_data))

packet_function = None

def get_tcp_from_ethernet(data):
    packet = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(data)
    if isinstance(packet.data, dpkt.ip.IP):
        return packet.data.data.data
    return None

def get_tcp_from_loopback(data):
    packet = dpkt.loopback.Loopback(data)
    if isinstance(packet.data, dpkt.ip.IP):
        return packet.data.data.data
    return None

def get_tcp_from_ip(data):
    packet = dpkt.ip.IP(data)
    if isinstance(packet, dpkt.ip.IP):
        return packet.data.data
    return None

def determine_packet_function(packet_data):
    type_functions = [get_tcp_from_ethernet, get_tcp_from_loopback, get_tcp_from_ip]
    for fn in type_functions:
        if fn(packet_data) is not None:
            if DEBUG: print 'Packet type:', fn.__name__.split('_')[-1]
            return fn
    return None

def tcp_data_from_packet_data(packet_data):
    global packet_function
    if not packet_function:
        packet_function = determine_packet_function(packet_data)
        if not packet_function:
            return None
    return packet_function(packet_data)


def tcp_data_from_filter(filter="", interface=None):
    # interface notes:
    #     iptap and pktap alone act like ",any" is appended
    #     'any' is a synonym for 'pktap,any'
    #     pktap and iptap do not work with permiscuous mode
    #     iptap seems to take no more than 23 characters
    #     pktap only takes 8 interfaces
    #     pcap.findalldevs() will return a list of interfaces
    #     Using iptap makes coding easier since pcap will only
    #     return the IP portion of the packet
    if not interface:
        interface="iptap"
    if DEBUG: print 'Capturing on interface(s):',interface
    # You must set timeout_ms. Not sure why the default doesn't work.
    pc = pcap.pcap(name=interface,           # default: None
                   snaplen=256 * 1024,       # default: 64k, but tcpdump uses 256k
                   timeout_ms=500)           # defailt: 500, but tcpdump uses 1000
    pc.setfilter(filter)
    for capture in pc:
        if not capture:
            continue
        timestamp, packet_data = capture
        if DEBUG: hex_dump_packet(packet_data)
        tcp_data = tcp_data_from_packet_data(packet_data)
        if tcp_data is not None:
            yield timestamp, tcp_data

def timestring(timestamp):
    # 00:14:21.836925
    t = time.localtime(timestamp)
    s = '{:0.6f}'.format(timestamp - int(timestamp))[1:]
    return '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}{}'.format(t.tm_hour, t.tm_min, t.tm_sec, s)

def print_tcp_data_from_filter(**kwargs):
    for timestamp, data in tcp_data_from_filter(**kwargs):
        print "{}    {}".format(timestring(timestamp), data)

# Only show packets containing actual data, i.e. no protocol-only
# packets, coming to my server on port 777.
filter = 'tcp dst port 777 and (tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-push != 0)'
print_tcp_data_from_filter(filter=filter)
```